How to dynamically unpivot data in BigQuery Standard SQL?
Suppose we have the following table on BigQuery:



product
price
country




product A
2
USA


product B
3
Canada



Is it possible to retrieve the following result set from the above via Standard SQL?



product
attribute
value




product A
price
2


product A
country
USA


product B
price
3


product B
country
Canada



The reason I want to do this is because the initial table in my scenario has an arbitrarily large number of columns (~300), each one of them corresponding to an attribute (e.g. price, country etc.) of the entities in the first column (products in this example). On top of this, the set of columns is frequently extended with newly added columns, so a hard-coded solution won't do unfortunately.

It is possible to do this in BigQuery, though not with Standard SQL. The way forward is to use procedural statements.
The basic thing you're doing is this:
    SELECT
        product,
        attribute,
        value,
      FROM
        products_dataset.products_table
   UNPIVOT(
        value FOR attribute IN (price, country)
   )

(using the UNPIVOT operator is much simpler than the approaches suggested in other answers, and is certainly part of the standard 'Google SQL')
Your problem: it's not possible to dynamically create the (price, country, ...) bit in standard SQL.
The Solution
We'll tackle this in two parts. First, how shall we dynamically obtain the list of columns?
Get the list of columns
This isn't too bad. We need to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:
    SELECT
        column_name,
      FROM
        `region-europe-west2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE
           table_schema = 'products_dataset'
       AND table_name = 'products_table'
       AND column_name != 'product'

Now you have a query that returns all the column names (except product) from your table. You must change europe-west2 to match the region/multiregion of products_dataset (select the Dataset in the UI and look at 'Data location').
For reasons that will soon become apparent, we'll aggregate the output into a single, comma-separated string:
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG(column_name, ', ') AS column_names,
      FROM
        `region-europe-west2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE
           table_schema = 'products_dataset'
       AND table_name = 'products_table'
       AND column_name != 'product'

This returns one row by one column holding the value price, country, ....
Build a query using BigQuery procedural commands
Remember, the sticking point is that we need to put arbitrary column names into the UNPIVOT expression.
Riding to our rescue is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, a command that takes a string and executes it as a SQL query!
We'll also use """ multiline strings and the || string concatenation operator.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
      SELECT
        product,
        attribute,
        value,
      FROM
        products_dataset.products_table
   UNPIVOT(
        value FOR attribute IN ("""
|| (
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG(column_name, ', ') AS column_names,
      FROM
        `region-europe-west2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE
           table_schema = 'products_dataset'
       AND table_name = 'products_table'
       AND column_name != 'product'
)
|| """)
)
"""

What does this do?
This solution should work. But what is it doing?
First, it executes a query to build a string that looks like price, country, ... (your list of columns).
Secondly, it concatenates this with the outer parts of the query, producing a single seamless UNPIVOT query with all the column names dynamically filled in.
Finally, it executes this query, giving you the desired result.

You can simply use a UNION Statement:
select product, 'price' as attribute, convert(varchar,price) as value 
from BigQuery
union
select product, 'country' as attribute, country as value
from BigQuery

Just keep in mind to convert any values to the most general type (usually varchar).

Thanks for this, but in my case the source table has LOTS of columns (~300) and their set is frequently extended with newly added columns. I was wondering whether there is a solution that does not need to hardcode the names of the columns.

Nice question. Yes, you can achieve this in BigQuery Standard SQL using the below query.
SELECT
  product,
  attribute,
  value
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST([ 
  STRUCT('price' AS attribute,CAST(price AS STRING) AS value), 
  STRUCT('country' AS attribute,country AS value) 
  ])

This query works by two steps.

Create an array of STRUCTs for each row in the table, where each STRUCT represents a key-value pair.
UNNEST() function is then used to transform each array into a set of rows.


Thanks a lot, but I am not looking at only a couple of columns, as the actual scenario has around 300 columns. Please take a look at the last paragraph in my original question - I added some more clarifications. Any idea on that would be more than welcome.

@StratosK Then write some code or use a tool to write out the sql for you then.

@MatBailie If this level of dynamicity is not possible from within SQL alone, then, yes, that's what I am going to do. But I thought I should investigate Plan A against the SO community first.
